# Does any unbounded directed set contain an unbounded, increasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory

Assume $D$ is a directed set such that there does *not* exist $d\in D$ satisfying $d\geq d'$ for all $d'\in D$.

Can we always find a sequence $(d_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that $d_{n+1}\geq d_n$ for all $n$, and such that there does *not* exist $d\in D$ satisfying $d\geq d_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$?

Is the result true? Is there an easy counter-example? Or only under some assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: Thank you, I am completely unfamiliar with ordinals. I assume this is a counter example of an unbounded directed set with no increasing, unbounded sequence, is that right?

Comment: @Navukido20: Yes, it is. Every increasing sequence in $D$ has an upper bound (and in fact a least upper bound).

Comment: Great, many thanks to both of you!